# How to use Quartiles to work the same as TI-83 calculator?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

The statistics book I am using defines quartiles the same as Method 1 explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile).

> Use the median to divide the ordered data set into two-halves.
> If there is an odd number of data points in the original ordered data set, do not include the median (the central value in the ordered list) in either half.
> If there is an even number of data points in the original ordered data set, split this data set exactly in half.
> The lower quartile value is the median of the lower half of the data. The upper quartile value is the median of the upper half of the data.
> This rule is employed by the TI-83 calculator boxplot and "1-Var Stats" functions.

For the following illustration, the numbers with yellow background represent the data while the curly braced three numbers represent their quartiles.

[image]

As `Quartiles` defined in Mathematica uses different algorithm, I create my own implementing the Method 1 above as follows.

```
CorrectedQuartile[raw_List] := Module[{data, length, Q1, Q2, Q3},
   data = Sort@raw;
   length = Length@data;
   Q2 = Median@data;
   If[Mod[length, 2] == 0,
    Q1 = Median@Take[data, length/2];
    Q3 = Median@Take[data, -length/2],
    Q1 = Median@Take[data, (length - 1)/2];
    Q3 = Median@Take[data, (1 - length)/2]
    ];
   {Q1, Q2, Q3}
   ];
```

## Question

My rule of thumb is "Writing our own functions must be the last resort". Is it possible to use the existing or built-in `Quartiles` to behaves the same as the Method 1 does?

Comment: The online help for `Quantile` gives 8 different definitions one of which almost certainly matches the Texas Instruments approach.  It also gives a general formula to be able to customize however you want.  I would expect this question to be closed.

Comment: It is very hard to choose the values for  `{{a,b},{c,d}}`.

Comment: Here's another "last resort": `tiQuartiles[list_] := 
  With[{med = Median[list]}, 
   Riffle[Median /@ Lookup[GroupBy[list, Sign[# - med] &], {-1, 1}], med]];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

I realized that different sets of parameters can be used:

```
corQuartiles[d_?ListQ] := Quantile[d, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4},
  {If[EvenQ[Length[d]], {1/2, 0}, {0, 1}], {0, 1}}]
```

Test:

```
# -> corQuartiles[#] & /@ Range /@ Range[2, 7]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2} -> {1, 3/2, 2}, {1, 2, 3} -> {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4} -> {3/2, 
>    5/2, 7/2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} -> {3/2, 3, 9/2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
>    6} -> {2, 7/2, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> {2, 4, 6}}
> ```

## Original answer

I've looked into the third parameter `{{a,b},{c,d}}` of `Quantile` but it seems that they cannot satisfy OP's demand. Maybe you still need to write it by yourself, like:

```
corQuartiles[d_?ListQ] := With[{n = Length[d]},
  If[EvenQ[n],
   Quartiles[d],
   Median /@ TakeList[Sort[d], {(n - 1)/2, 1, All}]
  ]]
```

Comment: How did you determine the "confusing" parameters?

Comment: @TooFatManNoNeck (1) `{a,b}` is obtained by solving $x=a+(n+b)q$ ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html)), since your illustration actually gives a series of $x_{n,q}$; (2)For linear interpolation between elements (instead of a certain element), we have `{c,d}={0,1}`.